# How can I stop this jQuery from bugging out?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

So I'm trying to create a box that has two layers: The front layer and the back layer. They're going to be stacked on top of each other so the back layer is hidden by default.

When you hover over the top of the box (front layer technically), then the front layer is supposed to slide up revealing the back layer. I tried to do this by using `.slideUp()` and `.slideDown()` but it kept bugging out revealing both layers at the same time. So then I switched to just `.slideUp()` and `.fadeIn()` but that didn't seem to help too much.

[image: bugging]

As you can see, it sometimes shows both divs when it's not supposed to and it also slides multiple times randomly. How could I make this more efficient?

Here is a [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9uw2q24h/1/)

**UPDATE:**

> Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must
>   include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the
>   shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself.
>   Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other
>   readers.

That is the reason people are voting to close this answer... What does this question not have, from that list?

```
Desired behavior? - Check
Specific problem? - Check
Shortest code necessary? - Check
Clear problem? - check
```

Comment: Care to explain the downvote? The script almost works, it just needs tweaking.

Comment: You should probably include hour code right in your question, not only a link to the fiddle.

Comment: Why? It would seem counter productive to put it into both posts.

Comment: Because that is how it is supposed to be done on SO. The main reason is that if for any reason jsFiddle would be taken down, your question would then become useless for others in the community. This is probably why you're getting donwnvotes and close votes. Note that there is a very clever code inclusion system here allowing a code like yours (html, css, js) to be executed directly from the question, just like it would be in a fiddle. However, a fiddle is still usefull was it only for the possibility to fork it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't really need to use slideUp and slideDown, you can achieve the slide effect by using the transform and transition CSS3 properties.

Updated JS fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/9uw2q24h/3/

Javascript:

```
$('.outer').hover(function() {
  $(this).children('.front').addClass('front-up');
}, function() {
  $(this).children('.front').removeClass('front-up');
});
```

CSS:

```
.outer {
  position: relative;

  .front,
  .back {
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .back {
    display: block;
  }
  .front {
    position: absolute;
    transition: 0.5s ease;
  }
  .front-up {
    transform: translateY(-100%);
  }
}
```

If you have to support older browsers, make sure to add the vendor prefixes to the transition and tranform rules (-webkit-, -moz-, etc.).

Comment: Nice solution, but I would add the class `.well` in the styling and give it a `margin-bottom:0`  for stability.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this like:

```
var running = false;
$('.outer').hover(function() {
  if (!running) {
    running = true;
    $(this).children('.front').slideUp(function() {
      $(this).next('.back').slideDown(function() {
        running = false;
      });
    });
  }
}, function() {
  if (!running) {
    running = true;
    $(this).children('.back').slideUp(function() {
      $(this).prev('.front').slideDown(function() {
          running = false;
      });
    });
  }
});
```

**Explanation**: as soon as the animation starts you save the status in a variable in order to avoid conflicts (otherwise it will be called again). Additionally with the `slideDown` and `slideUp` combined you have a much smoother animation. You had a not very nice flickering with your combination of `fadeOut` and `slideDown`

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/dL7ckq6b/

Answer (score 1):

With a slight tweak to your CSS, specifically making your elements' position property absolute, will cause your back element to be behind your front element from the start, now you only have to show/hide your front element.

**Javascript:**

```
$('.outer').hover(function() {
$('.front').slideUp();
    console.log("IN");  
}, function() {
  $('.front').slideDown();
  console.log("OUT");  
});
```

I did also update the CSS to more clearly show the effect happening.

**CSS:**

```
.outer {
  .front,
  .back {
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    padding: 20px 10px;
    border: 2px solid yellow;
  }

  .front {
    z-index: 10;
    background-color: red;
  }

  .back {
    z-index: 0;
    background-color: blue;
  }
}
```

Here is the JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/z8e7eb4b/